# C++: Program crashes when I try to access a private class string variable. Why is this, and what can I do to fix it?

Tags: c++, string, class, private-members

I am writing a bank account program that provides a menu system for the user, which allows them to choose between 4 options: A) Add a customer, B) Print all customer data, C) Update customer data, and D) Exit program. Each option performs separate tasks. **The option I am focused on for this question is Option A**.

Option A is supposed to generate a new bank account object and ask the user to input the account holder name, the initial deposit for the account (how much money to start with for the new account), and the interest rate. It then needs to set these values to the correct private values in the bankAccount class for any given object.

Code for main.cpp before Option B (there is a little more code after this, hence the lack of backward brackets at the end, but I want to try and keep this more concise):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "header.h"
#include "implementation.cpp"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //array of bankAccount class objects (up to 20)
    bankAccount account[20];
    string menuInput = "";           //used for menu loop input
    string accNameInput = "";        //used for account customer name user input
    float depositInput = 0;   //used for initial deposit input
    float interestInput = 0;  //used for initial interest input
   // int customerCount = 0;    //used to compare to static int to determine # of customers in memory

    int static i = 0;

    //while loop keeps user in the menu until they choose to exit program

    while (true)
    {

    cout << endl << "Enter a letter option below: "
        << endl << endl << "A: Add a customer" << endl << "B: Print all customer data available"
        << endl << "C: Update customer data" << endl << "D: End program" << endl << endl;

    cin >> menuInput;

 //Option A: Add a customer
 if (menuInput == "A" || menuInput == "a")
 {
     //checking for max customer limit
    if (i > 19)
    {
        cout << endl << "Cannot add customer; Max customer capacity reached." << endl;
    }
    else //
     {
        ///Creates a new customer account and asks for new customer name,
        ///initial deposit amount, & interest
       cout << endl << "Bank account #" << (i + 1) << " created." << endl;
       bankAccount account[i];     //new bank account object created

        //time to set the name for our new customer...
       cout << endl << "Enter customer name for account #" << (i + 1) << ": " << endl;
       cin >> accNameInput;


       //setting initial deposit amount
       cout << endl << "Enter initial deposit amount for account #" << (i + 1) << ": " << endl;
       cin >> depositInput;


       //setting initial interest rate
       cout << endl << "Enter interest rate (without % sign): " << endl;
       cin >> interestInput;


 account[i].setInterestRate(interestInput);
 account[i].setBalance(depositInput);
 account[i].setAccountHolderName(accNameInput);


        //increments the account number counter
        i++;
     }
 }
```

The problem persists with setAccountHolderName() found on the last line here:

```
account[i].setInterestRate(interestInput);
account[i].setBalance(depositInput);
account[i].setAccountHolderName(accNameInput);
```

When I call the class functions setInterestRate and setBalance to set the input values to their respective private class variables, the program proceeds like normal and takes the user back to the main menu as it should. **But calling setAccountHolderName crashes the program and returns this value: -1073741819 (0xC0000005).**

I'll include some code from the header and implementation files below to show how I have accountHolderName code programmed in:

header.h (includes accountHolderName get/set functions):

```
///Name of file: header.h
#ifndef HEADER_H_INCLUDED
#define HEADER_H_INCLUDED
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class bankAccount
{
    //private data values
    string accountHolderName;
    int accountNumber;
    //static int accCounter;  //keeps track of account numbers
    float balance;
    float interestRate;

public:

    //Default constructor
    bankAccount();

    ///Getters/setters for all private member variables
    //accountNumber
    int getAccountNumber();
    void setAccountNumber(int accNum);

    //accountHolderName
    string getAccountHolderName();
    void setAccountHolderName(string accName);
```

implementation.cpp (includes accountHolderName implementation):

```
///Name of file: implementation.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "header.h"

using namespace std;

//static int definition (guess you have to define static members here?)
//int bankAccount::accCounter;

//Default constructor
bankAccount::bankAccount()
{
    accountHolderName = "";
    accountNumber = 0;
   // accCounter = 0;
    balance = 0;
    interestRate = 0;
}

    ///Getters/setters for all private member variables
    //accountNumber
int bankAccount::getAccountNumber()
{
    return accountNumber;
}
void bankAccount::setAccountNumber(int accNum)
{
    accountNumber = accNum;
}

    //accountHolderName
string bankAccount::getAccountHolderName()
{
    return accountHolderName;
}
void bankAccount::setAccountHolderName(string accName)
{
    accountHolderName = accName;
}
```

It seems like messing with the code in certain ways (such as completely deleting the code that comes after Option A's code, commenting out `accountHolderName = "";` in the default constructor, etc.) will temporarily allow `account[i].setAccountHolderName(accNameInput);` to function without crashing the program, but this is incredibly inconsistent and confuses me even more. I'm not sure if the issue has to do with memory or what. I have also tried using `cout` to see if the input variable `accNameInput` from main.cpp is getting stored to, which it is.

Sorry if this is simply too much code or explaining; this is my first post and I just wanted to provide a good chunk of my code so you could see the full scale of things. **All I am trying to do here is access the bankAccount class private string variable, `accountHolderName`, and store user input into each new object**.

I tried troubleshooting this issue online but couldn't seem to find anything that had a similar issue. I'm not sure what I'm missing; any help or guidance would be incredibly appreciated.

Comment: Try shortening your question to about 10 lines - a minimal reproducible example, the full output of the crush, and what you don't understand about it. No background about banks needed.

Comment: Not related to your bug, but you really don't want to be `#include` a `.cpp` file.

Comment: `bankAccount account[i];     //new bank account object created` -- This actually compiled?  This is not valid C++, as you are attempting to create a local array with `i` elements.  If you switched to a compiler that actually stopped you from using code like this (such as Visual Studio, or g++ with the proper compiler flags), you probably wouldn't have an issue.

Comment: `bankAccount account[20];` and `bankAccount account[i];`. Why are you declaring `account` twice?

Comment: What do you think the line `bankAccount account[i];` in your loop does? Remove it. You are creating a new temporary VLA array of accounts that gets destroyed at the end of every loop cycle.

Comment: @NadavS [Here's a link to shortcut links](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting). For example `[mre]` expands to [mre].

Comment: @super The OP probably does not know what a VLA is, and is not aware that defining the original array already creates all the account objects. (@OP: `bankAccount account[20];` creates 20 fully initialized bank accounts, ready to be used!)

Comment: It's like every other post from a new programmer uses this VLA stuff.  I wished in the future, g++ or whatever compiler gives this option by default would turn this "feature" off, and only allow it via compiler flag.  It only confuses the new programmer, making them think that their code is valid C++.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yeah, this nonsense wasn't around when *we* learned C++! ;-).

Comment: @NadavS Thank you, I will keep your words in mind next time! I know this was probably frustratingly long haha

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes, this was the issue!! I had overlooked this small line of code not realizing I was actually creating and wasting a new array of the same name. I thought at the time I was "creating the new object", even though now I see I already did that at the beginning of my program for all 20. I feel silly now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, this line:

```
bankAccount account[i];     //new bank account object created
```

Isn't allowed in C++, but some compilers (g++) allow it as an extension since they do formally support variable stack arrays with the C compiler.

Further, that declaration overrides the variable of the same name declared at a higher scope

But then you get to these lines:

```
account[i].setInterestRate(interestInput);
account[i].setBalance(depositInput);
account[i].setAccountHolderName(accNameInput);
```

But valid indices of an array range for `0..i-1`  So you're already in undefined behavior with your array index out of bounds.

I suspect you really meant this:

```
bankAccount newAccount;     //new bank account object created

...

newAccount.setInterestRate(interestInput);
newAccount.setBalance(depositInput);
newAccount.setAccountHolderName(accNameInput);

account[i] = newAccount;
i++;
```

Comment: Since the code, that you are referencing is in the `main`, `this->bankaccount[i]` will not compile, due to non-existing `this`.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius - fixed.

Comment: This does what I'd like it to, thanks a bunch. I'm using Code Blocks and interestingly it didn't throw an error at me when I used ```bankAccount account[i]```. Either way, I realized I had already declared 20 of the account objects at the start and this line was redundant and killing my program.